# Passing Type to Dio Interceptors Flutter

Tags: flutter, interceptor, dio, networkmanager

I am using a base network manager and custom Dio interceptors. I am getting type of the response via the network request sender method like this:

```
Future<IResponseModel<R>> send<T extends BaseModel<T>, R extends BaseModel<R>>(
     // R is the expected response type.
     required R responseModel,
```

I also want to know the expected response type (which is R in this case) in the methods of interceptors (for example: "onRequest").
Here's the code that I want to have:

```
Class CustomInterceptors extends Interceptor with NetworkParsers {
  @override
  Future<void> onRequest<R>(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
        // R will be the expected response type.
```

However, just as expected it says that this function is "not a valid override of Interceptor.onRequest" and doesn't allow. How can I overcome this problem, how can I know the expected response type in the interceptors too? Is there any method that I can pass the response type to the interceptor just before a request is sent from the network manager?

Answer (score 0):

`response.data.runtimeType` won't give you the type you expect to have as `<R>`.

So, it seems that the response data is not yet de-serialized in the interceptor.

Comment: I know that runtimType doesn't give me the type I expect, I just want to learn if there is any workaround to learn the type.